# Upload image xcode wcf service

Tags: xcode

I have service wcf that has function used to upload image

1

```
Public Function Upload(ByVal UploadData As UploadData) As UploadReturn
```

2

```
Public Structure UploadData
    Public StrStream As Stream
End Structure
```

3 xcode

I am using `afhttprequestmanager`

```
parameters:@{@"StrStream":[NSData dataWithData:imageData]}
```

How can I send data from xcode to this function as stream?

Comment: Sorry, but can you please rephrase your question? And your tags? I have no idea what you're talking about and I guess this has nothing to do with Xcode (it just happens to be your IDE) but iOS development in general. Which language are you using? Swift or Objc?

Comment: i am using objec and i want to upload image from xcode to wcf service